# Installing Debian Squeeze Backport with Dependencies

Tags: linux, debian, debian-squeeze

I have added `squeeze-backports` to my apt sources.list, and updated.  The backport instructions say that you use the -t switch to install a package, plus its dependencies, to get around the default pinning:

```
 $ sudo apt-get -t squeeze-backport install xen-linux-system-amd64

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xen-linux-system-amd64 : Depends: xen-linux-system-3.2.0-0.bpo.2-amd64 but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

This package exists, so why isn't it installed as a dependency?

```
$ apt-cache search  xen-linux-system-3.2.0-0.bpo.2-amd64
xen-linux-system-3.2.0-0.bpo.2-amd64 - Xen system with Linux 3.2 on 64-bit PCs (meta-package)
```

I can add it to the install list, but then I just get the next dependency not being installed.  What can I do to say "yes, go ahead, find the dependencies and install them too"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do use the interactive console program `aptitude` for package management. When aptitude discovers a problem it offers to search for solutions. After that you can go through the found solutions, inspect them and then decide for one. Maybe that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've taken to using the 3.2 kernel on new Squeeze installs for Xen hosts. Here is my set of agis:

```
apt-get -t squeeze-backports install linux-image-3.2.0-0.bpo.4-amd64 firmware-linux-free
```

reboot

```
apt-get install xen-hypervisor-amd64  xen-utils xen-tools xen-utils-common xen-docs-4.0
```

Comment: What are "agis"?

Comment: @cpast agi = apt-get install. That's a useful alias to have for `agi <package>` instead of `sudo apt-get install <package>`.